# Is there a way to redirect 404 errors coming from web routes only to the homepage?

Tags: laravel

I would like to redirect to the homepage whenever a **web** route page returns 404 or 403 error codes.

The answer here seems to redirect all routes, regardless if they are an API route or a WEB route: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35718010/1236183

Is that possible?

Comment: Try to add a check $request->expectsJson() if it's true then the request is expecting a JSON response otherwise you can redirect as in the mentioned issue link.

Comment: Thanks @faizan.sh, I endded up doing 
`if(!$request->expectsJson())
            return redirect('/');
        else
            return parent::render($request, $e);`

Answer (score 1):

you can put this in top of `api.php`

```php
Route::any('{any?}', function ($any = null) {
    return redirect('/');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

it will catch all the 404 and redirect to home page