# Catching all other routes in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I am trying to send all undefined routes in a specific controller like this:

```
Route::get('/{slug:[A-Za-z0-9:/]+}', ['uses' => '\Site\Http\Controllers\AppController@index'])
```

It works in Lumen 5.1 but no chance in Laravel 5.2.

How can I setup such general match routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it, but something like this should work:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'AppController@index')->where('slug', '([A-Za-z0-9:/]+)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this after all of the relevant other routes:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', '\Site\Http\Controllers\AppController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

Route Undefined = 404 Error, so you can handle it properly.

Look at this question:
[Redirect to homepage if route doesnt exist in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479409/redirect-to-homepage-if-route-doesnt-exist-in-laravel-5)