# Laravel error handling when route does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route to show my users' profile in my laravel project. But when you go to an url and fill in a username that does not exist it gives a nasty error, obviously because that username doesn't exist in the database.

Has anyone any idea how I can error handle this?

Here's my route:

```
Route::get('user/{name}', 'userController@showUser');
```

Here's my function:

```
public function showUser($name)
    {
        $user = User::where('name' , '=', $name)->firstOrFail();
        return view('user.show', compact('user'));
    }
```

This is what I've tried but doesn't seem to work since I get this error:
View not found

```
$user = User::where('name' , '=', $name)->first();
        if(!empty($user)){
            return view('user.show', compact('user','projects'));
        }else{
            return view('user');
        }
```

Comment: don't use `firstOrFail`, but `first`, check if you found something yourself and react by redirecting or whatever you want to do.

Comment: @Pevara That's the issue I have, I don't know exactly how to redirect when there are no results. I am failry new to laravel :)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        $user = User::where('name' , '=', $name)->first();
        if(!empty($user)){
            return view('user.show', compact('user','projects'));
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('/routeWhereYouWannaSend');
        }
```

For more info read [HTTP Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects)

**2nd Solution:** If you want to redirect to Homepage on route(s) that doesn't exist at all [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479409/redirect-to-homepage-if-route-doesnt-exist-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1):

you can use first method to get username from user table

```
public function showUser($name){
        $user = User::where('name' , '=', $name)->first();
        if(!empty($user)){
          return view('user.show', compact('user'));
       }

}
```

}

Lets make sure your view file is in user folder

Comment: What is Error message?