# default route for wrong url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to create default route for wrong url in laravel.if I have typed tst instead of test It should redirect to default url '/' is it possible to restrict wrong url in laravel 
I have the routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to homepage if route doesnt exist in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479409/redirect-to-homepage-if-route-doesnt-exist-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Check here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-create-a-custom-404-error-page

Comment: This is not the solution, but just want to share that In laravel 5.5, error page now has it's own template. So need to worry about error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of all routes, add following route:

```
Route::any('{any}', function () {
    return redirect()->url('/');
});
```

Or you can write directly like:

```
Route::redirect('/{any}', '/', 301);
```

This will take any routes except listed one and redirect to url.