# Double slash in URL is automatically converted in single slash in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am working on one site where I need to show 404 pages when someone adds double slash in URL.

I have written logic to check REQUEST_URI and if there is double slash then I am showing 404 pages...

But when I add double slash in URL it shows single slash in REQUEST_URI but in URL, it is double slash...

here I attached a screenshot for the same issue.

> For Example: if i enter **www.example.com//check** -> then its is coming
>   as **/check** in **REQUEST_URI** but i want it should come as **//check**
>
> Site is hosted in **AWS cloud load balancer (ELB)**. in local setting its
>   working proeper but in production its creating issue.

Can someone help me how can I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: An extra `"/"` in URL breaks the `URL`. That value must be encoded if you want to put it in a query string.

Comment: I am not putting that slash in URL. I just want to add logic if someone manipulates URL in the browser it should not show that page it should show 404 page

Comment: for example, if you open any landing page from my site and  you add extra slash in url then it should not show that page @AndreiLupuleasa

Comment: there are solutions for what you are trying to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479409/redirect-to-homepage-if-route-doesnt-exist-in-laravel-5

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa this is not working I have tried before.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.5.5 introduced a new feature in routing, called Route::fallback(). Basically, if no route is matched, then fallback function is a way to override default 404 page and introduce additional logic. Here’s how it works.

```
Route::fallback(function() {
    return 'Hm, why did you land here somehow?';
});
```

Comment: actually, we don't have routes for all page some routes are landing page and we are catching all routes using Route::get('{catchall}', 'MyController@suburl')->where('catchall', '.*'); so this solution will not work

Comment: I think we need to fix this on server level that why the server is not returning double slash from url

Comment: its also returning same /check